# Ruby on Rails : Storing the pluck result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im creating a library management system as part of a college assignment.
Im currently stuck on obtaining the result of pluck.

The task Im trying to do here is to display a list of books that are currently in the table.
Ive been primarily a PHP programmer so ruby on rails is a whole new world for me.

From doing external research I found out about object.pluck.

```
Book.pluck(:isbn,:title,:description,:author,:status)
```

My knowledge of the above snippet is that Im pulling from all book objects there details.
What I want to do is have a loop that will output each book followed by an edit button.
In PHP this would be a form inside of a for loop. but with ruby I dont really know how to do it

In my head I want to store the result of the pluck in an array of books[].
Then use a loop to iterate through that loop and output details of the book stored at index i.
But Im not sure how to store the result of pluck?

Comment: In Rails, instance variables defined in your controller are available to views. So just add this to your controller action: `@books = Book.pluck(:isbn,:title,:description,:author,:status)` and loop through `@books` to print all books in your `index.html.erb` like `@books.each do |book|`

Comment: Doesn't sound like you want to pluck - I'd just use `Book.all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the whole books collection to a variable, and then use it in view:

```
# in controller's action (most likely index)

@books = Book.all

# in index.html.* view (haml example):

- @books.each do |book|
  = link_to 'Edit book', edit_book_path(book)
```

Make sure you go through [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) (really useful).

Comment: The book object in the books_controller is called (@)book it = Book.all So on the index of my site (home.html.erb) I have the following loop : (@)book.each do |book| link_to 'Edit book', edit_book_path(book) end However the each command cannot be found.

Comment: @DetectiveClarke to be able to use `@books` in `home.html.erb` you have to define it in the proper controller's action. The controller''s action has to have corresponding view, only there you can use the `@books` variable. Otherwise in your `home.html.erb` you could simply do `Book.all.each do |book|
  = link_to 'Edit book', edit_book_path(book)` (without having any variables defined elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `as_json`

Example:

```
@books = Book.all.as_json(only: [:id, :isbn,:title,:description,:author,:status])
```

and then iterate over `@books` array
i.e

```
- @books.each do |book|
   = link_to 'Edit book', edit_book_path(book['id'])
```

OR

You can use `map` like below example

```
@books = Book.all.map{ |b| {id: b.id, isbn: b.isbn, title: b.title, description: b.description, author: b.author, status: b.status}}
```

Then `@books` gives you the output as array of books hash..

Then you can Iterate over it like below code

```
- @books.each do |book|
   = link_to 'Edit book', edit_book_path(book[:id])
```

May this will work for you

Comment: this `result_arr` 1) has bad/non-conventional name 2) it is local and won't be available in any view 3) even if it would be visible, how would you iterate over this variable? This is not useful answer

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I have updated code, thanks for your help

Comment: this is still not very efficient and has not much sense.. `map` will throw `undefined method` error and few more inefficiencies